# The clearLine() method doesn't clear the line in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

When I was using the **clearLine()** function of readline:

```
readline.clearLine(process.stdout);
```

I noticed that in **WebStorm** it won't actually clear the line and continue outputting on the same line,

**example:**

```
waiting ... 0%waiting ... 16%waiting ... 33%waiting ... 50%waiting ... 66%waiting ... 83%waiting ... 100%
```

However, if I go and run the file through command prompt the `clearLine()` function works perfectly.

Why is it that **WebStorm** does this and is there something I need to change?

Give the suggestion to me

Answer (score 1):

`clearLine()` and `cursorTo()` are undefined when process.stdout is not a **tty**. And Node console in WebStorm is non-Tty, as node process is started with input/output streams redirection. Please see [WEB-1933](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1933).